# Prove that Integer linear programming (ILP) is in NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np, integer-programming

Help is needed, I've tried to solve it by myself but I could find any reasonable solution which is solid enough. this is what I've wrote:

> Consider a 0-1 ILP, where each variable x1,x2...,xn can assume values
>   0 or 1. The number of constraints is m.
>
> We can choose all possible 2n assignments of x1, x2...xn in
>   non-deterministic manner.
>
> Checking the feasibility of each assignment takes O(nm) time, and
>   Computing the value of the objective function for each feasible
>   assignment takes O(n) time Since a nondeterministic manner considers
>   all assignments simultaneously. Thus, we have a non-deterministic
>   polynomial time.
>
> Due to Karp

Please provide a better solution

Comment: If I gave you what I claim is a solution (call me Oracle), how long would it take to check it?

Comment: NP is equivalent to: "If the answer is YES, then you can show that it is YES in polynomial time, given the right hint".

Comment: @gnasher729 I get your point, but I wouldn't ask my question if I wasn't stuck... can you help?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/69427/755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can show that a problem is in NP by demonstrating the existence of a polynomial time verifier. In this case, such a verifier would be provided the *values* of $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, and would need to answer the question "do these values of $x_1, \dots, x_n$ form a solution"? In this case, all you need to do is check that all $m$ contraints are satisfied.

Comment: Is there a solution that uses a simplex method?

Comment: I don't claim to be well-versed in linear programming, but I believe not, as the simplex method appears to have a worst case exponential time complexity. If you have to use a particular method, I suggest you ask about it in a new question. In the meantime, please keep this answer accepted if it answers your original question.

Comment: I agree with your observation

Comment: What if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are of exponential size w.r. to given $A,b,c$?